# Replace elements in a list of lists python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
     list=[]
     *some code to append elements to list*

     list=[['a','bob'],['a','bob'],['a','john']]
```

I want to go through this list and change all instances of 'bob to 'b' and leave others unchanged.

```
    for x in list:
       for a in x:
          if "bob" in a:
             a.replace("bob", 'b')
```

After printing out x it is still the same as list, but not as follows:

```
    list=[['a','b'],['a','b'],['a','john']]
```

Why is the change not being reflected in list?

Comment: you are making a copy of things in list by `for a in x`, and not directly pointing to the element of `x`.

Comment: Side note: never shadow built-ins. Use `list_` or `L` instead of `list` for your variable name.

Comment: @jpp or preferably something less generic that describes the contents... `names` or `letter_and_name` or something... :)

Answer (score 6):

Because `str.replace` doesn't work *in-place*, it [returns a copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). As immutable objects, you need to *assign* the strings to elements in your list of lists.

You can assign directly to your list of lists if you extract indexing integers via `enumerate`:

```
L = [['a','bob'],['a','bob'],['a','john']]

for i, x in enumerate(L):
    for j, a in enumerate(x):
        if 'bob' in a:
            L[i][j] = a.replace('bob', 'b')
```

Result:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'john']]
```

More Pythonic would be to use a list comprehension to create a new list. For example, if only the second of two values contains names which need checking:

```
L = [[i, j if j != 'bob' else 'b'] for i, j in L]
```

Comment: The "more pythonic" part isn't really a generic one considering the fact that `bob` can come anywhere in the sublist.

Comment: @Austin, Possibly. Given the example input, I'm happy to wait a little longer before making it more generic :)

Comment: Using `replace` with list-comprehension seems handle all cases, but then it's upto OP. :)

Comment: @Austin, Now I'm worried about someone called `mobob` being renamed `mob`.

Comment: @jpp don't forget poor "bobby" :)

Comment: Lol. If you think so, use `if a == 'bob':` instead of `if 'bob' in a:`.

Comment: or bobaganoush hahah

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a dictionary object of python

```
import numpy as np
L = [['a','bob'],['a','bob'],['a','john']]
dic = {'bob':'b'} # you can specify more changes here
new_list = [dic.get(n, n) for n in np.concatenate(L)]
print(np.reshape(new_list,[-1,2]).tolist())
```

Result is

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'john']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use a simple example, but basically `x` is another variable and isn't linked to the list element. You have to change the list element directly in order to alter the list.

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
for x in l:
    x=x+1
```

This doesn't change the list

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
for i,x in enumerate(l):
    l[i]=x+1
```

this changes the list

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little to the party, but a more Pythonic way of doing this is using a `map` and a `list comprehension`. It can operate on a list of the list with any number of values.

```
l = [['a','bob'],['a','bob'],['a','john']]

[list(map(lambda x: x if x != 'bob' else 'b', i)) for i in l]
```

it gives you the desired output

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'john']]
```

The main idea is that the inner loop is iterating through the inner loop and using the simple `lambda` function to perform the replacement.

I hope that this helps anyone else who is looking out for something similar.

Comment: I was looking for this. Many thanks! @lu5er

Answer (score 0):

This is the case because you are only changing the temporary variable a.
list = [1,2,3]
for i in list:
   i+=1

list will still be [1,2,3]

you have to edit the string based on its index in the list