# Basic question about replacing entries in list of lists according to if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I change this code so the I replace the elements for a different if condition?
In the code below I change replace the 3 with 5. 
But what if the wanted to replace the entry to 5 if any sub-list entry is larger than 30?
Example: If L[i][j] > 30 I get [[3,3],[5,5],[5,1], [5,8]]

```
L = [[3,3],[444,1111],[45,1], [90,8]]

for i, x in enumerate(L):
    for j, a in enumerate(x):
        if 3 in a:
            L[i][j] = a.replace(3, 5)
```

****** Disclaimer *******:
The example was taken from this enclosed question for the sake of convenience. My aim in this question is to understand how to use the indexes so it fits a different type of if condition.

[Replace elements in a list of lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483266/replace-elements-in-a-list-of-lists-python)

Comment: I do understand how the above works. I have trouble understanding how to change to **indexes** so it fits a different case where the if condition in slightly different. Could you be oh so kind and help with that?

Comment: `L = [[i, j if j <= 30 else 5] for i, j in L]`?

Comment: I dont see why you would have to change the indexes for the example condition you asked for. Just do if a > 30: L[i][j] = 5 to achieve that.

Comment: I also don't follow how indices are relevant here

Comment: tibetish as long as you cant specify what about indexes you dont understand, its impossible to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

### Quick and dirty answer:

```
L = [[3,3],[444,1111],[45,1], [90,8]]

L = [[5 if value < 30 else 5 for value in list ] for list in L]

print(L)
```

out:

```
[[3, 3], [5, 5], [5, 1], [5, 8]]
```

### Better way using a function

If you want to replace the values then it's better to create a simple function as shown below. You seem to have copied the code from somewhere else, so I will try my best to explain to you what is going on below.

Our original list is shown below:

```
  L = [[3,3],[444,1111],[45,1], [90,8]]
```

The function below is defined to accept 3 values, the first value is the list to be manipulated, the second is the condition, as in replace if number is > condition. The third value is the new value to replace the values that satisfy the condition.

```
  def replace_greater_than(List,condition = 30,new_value = 5):

        L = [[value if value < condition else new_value for value in list ] for list in List]
```

Here we are using a concept know as nested list comprehension. Start by reading it from right to left. We are looping through every list in List (notice the case), please note that "list" in the code can be replaced with any variable name that you want, but i just called it "list" to improve readability.

So now we are looping through our initial list and we are retrieving the inner lists with each iteration.Then we perform list comprehension again on the inner lists that we just retrieved, so now we are looping on the values in the list themselves.

Finally in the inner list comprehension we set a condition, which is passed on by the user, if the value is less than the set condition or threshold then return the same value else return the specified new value.

### How to use the function:

Example: here we place the condition as 30 and the value as 5

```
replace_greater_than(List = L, condition = 30, value = 5)
```

out:

```
[[3, 3], [5, 5], [5, 1], [5, 8]]
```

Example: We can also call the function without passing any values to the parameters because we already set the default values of our function earlier; condition = 30, new_value = 5.

```
replace_greater_than(List = L)
```

out:

```
[[3, 3], [5, 5], [5, 1], [5, 8]]
```

Example: Finally, we can also pass custom values to our function. The function below will replace all the values greater than 100 with the new_value of 23

```
replace_greater_than(List = L, condition = 100, new_value = 23)
```

out:

```
[[3, 3], [23, 23], [45, 1], [90, 8]]
```

Here are some sources to help you get started with learning python:

- [Great free Course covering all the basics by Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrxD0HtieHhS8VzuMCfQD4uJ9yne1mE6)
- [List Comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)
- [Functions in python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial)

Some channels on Youtube that I recommend:

- [Real Python](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI0vQvr9aFn27yR6Ej6n5UA)
- [Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5)
- [DataCamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Rf4fZDQ0yw&list=PLjgj6kdf_snaw8QnlhK5f3DzFDFKDU5f4)

Comment: @MjH , hope this helps, if you need any clarifications, feel free to comment below :D

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a loop through all elements, then you have condition and action when condition is met.

```
for i, x in enumerate(L):                 #loop
    for j, a in enumerate(x):             #loop
        if 3 in a:                        #condition  
            L[i][j] = a.replace(3, 5)     #action
```

You want to change **condition** to `if L[i][j] > 30` (already in your question), and you want to change **action** to replace or reassign entry, which is straightforward `L[i][j] = 5`.

In above code `a` is `L[i][j]`, so you can write **condition** a bit differently.

I will let you modify code yourself and test. You don't need to use list comprehension at this point.

Comment: I don't understand what this answer adds to what they already have. At all.

Comment: I agree with you that it looks super basic. Where I disagree with you is in blaming person that he doesn't know basics. My attempt is to point to those basic elements so person may grasp them.

Comment: I didn't blame anybody. It's a statement that I believed to be true and it was; whether or not that is uncomfortable, is up to the person. But now you're deflecting from the fact that I don't think your answer adds anything to the understanding of the OP

Comment: Great, thanks !That helped me.  I'm coding for only **one** month so thank you for being **patient** and **clear**. I now **understand** where I went wrong.

Comment: I agree with MjH, that the answer might be helpfull for the OP as he might need to revisit loop basics, but its not answering the question he posted. Entire question should be closed as it is unclear and not useful.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm new here, so would appreciate guidance from more experienced fellow as you're. Could you please elaborate where my answer is missing the intent of stackoverflow? Not sure that comments is good place to ask this question, actually. Is there a chat or something?

Comment: @MjH there is a [python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) :) But it seems that your answer was useful to the OP; I didn't intend for it to go further, but I'm regularly in the room

Answer (score 0):

Thea easy way to do it is to iterate over each item in each list and change items via an 'if' statement.

Create a statement which will return either the item it is given, or 3 if the number is equal to 5.

```
replace = lambda i: 3 if i==5 else i
```

Next, iterate through the nested lists. This can be written out in two ways, via list comprehension or as nested for statements.

```
l = [[replace(l2)for l2 in l1] for l1 in l]

for l1 in l:
    for l2 in l1:
        l2 = replace(l2)
```

When we run the code we get:

```
print (l)
>>> [[3, 3], [444, 1111], [45, 1], [90, 8]]
```

To make the code change any items <30 we can change the if statement we made at the start.

```
replace = lambda i: 3 if i<30 else i
```

Printing the new code gives:

```
print (l)
>>> [[3, 3], [444, 1111], [45, 3], [90, 3]]
```

Note, using x.replace() works for strings not integers, you can play with int() and str() if you need to use .replace().